# Node-libcurl post takes more time than other Node Packages like Request/Axios/Needle etc

Tags: node-libcurl

I am planning to use this node-libcurl package for my project and did a comparison with other npm packages like Request/Axios/Needle. I used the same request to post through node-libcurl and other packages mentioned above. Looks like node-libcurl continuously takes 9 secs whereas others are taking only 300 millisecs. Sample code below

```
 let opts: CurlOptionValueType = {
            sslVerifyPeer: true,
            verbose:true,
            url: this.getConfigurationValueForOperation(req.operationName,"url"),
            timeoutMs:this.getConfigurationValueForOperation(req.operationName,"timeOutInMillis")
        };
```

let resp = await curly(url, opts);

For above I am seeing ElapsedTimeInMillis: 9431 and for other packages its 300 millsecs. Please let me know if I am missing some setting in the options?

Thanks,
Chinmaya